# Autowire not working in junit test

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. bar gets autowired in the junit test, but why doesn't bar inside foo get autowired?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"beans.xml"})
public class BarTest {  

    @Autowired
    Object bar;

    @Test
    public void testBar() throws Exception {
            //this works
        assertEquals("expected", bar.someMethod());
            //this doesn't work, because the bar object inside foo isn't autowired?
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        assertEquals("expected", foo.someMethodThatUsesBar());
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "bar inside foo"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Foo isn't a managed spring bean, you are instantiating it yourself. So Spring's not going to autowire any of its dependencies for you.

Answer (score 8):

You are just creating a new instance of Foo. That instance has no idea about the Spring dependency injection container. You have to autowire foo in your test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"beans.xml"})
public class BarTest {  

    @Autowired
    // By the way, the by type autowire won't work properly here if you have
    // more instances of one type. If you named them  in your Spring
    // configuration use @Resource instead
    @Resource(name = "mybarobject")
    Object bar;
    @Autowired
    Foo foo;

    @Test
    public void testBar() throws Exception {
            //this works
        assertEquals("expected", bar.someMethod());
            //this doesn't work, because the bar object inside foo isn't autowired?
        assertEquals("expected", foo.someMethodThatUsesBar());
    }
}
```